# How to pass C++ pointer to Fortran?

Tags: c++, pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have the following C++ code:

```
extern "C" void C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN(double *doublearray)
{
    doublearray=new double [10];
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        doublearray[i]=i;
}
```

The array `doublearray` should be passed to Fortran:

```
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN(cdoublearray) BIND(C, NAME='C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
      IMPLICIT NONE
      TYPE(C_PTR)  :: cdoublearray
    END SUBROUTINE 
  END INTERFACE

  TYPE(C_PTR) :: cdoublearray
  REAL(C_DOUBLE), POINTER :: fdoublearray(:)
  CALL C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN((cdoublearray))
  CALL C_F_POINTER( cdoublearray, fdoublearray,[10])  
  WRITE (*, *) fdoublearray
  END
```

However, the code crashed at `C_F_POINTER`:  after calling `C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN`, `cdoublearray` is equal to `0`. 
Could anyone help me to take a look at it?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Does it compile? Does it run wrong?

Comment: after called `C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN`, `cdoublearray` is equal to 0, so when running to `C_F_POINTER` the program cracked.

Comment: Why you pass `cdoublearray` as a copy `((cdoublearray))`?

Comment: What is cracked? Did it print something?

Comment: Do you mean "crashed"?

Comment: oh sorry, it's 'crashed'.

Comment: @VladimirF sorry it's `CALL C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN(cdoublearray)`

Comment: DID IT PRINT SOMETHING?

Comment: Oh, I am confused, the crash happened at `write(*,*)fdoublearray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a copy of the pointer here

```
CALL C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN((cdoublearray))
```

the copy is made by the second set of parentheses. Therefore the `cdoublearray` is never changed and keeps the original undefined value which happens to e 0.

Try

```
CALL C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN(cdoublearray)
```

but be careful, you will still have a problem when deallocating the array. That must be done from C++.

You must also adjust the procedure to accept a pointer to pointer. See @AlexenderVogt's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have changed the code to free memory by C++.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the pointer by value, and not by reference. Your C++ code should read

```
extern "C" void C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN(double *& doublearray)
{
    doublearray=new double [10];
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        doublearray[i]=i;
}
```

Note the `C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN(double *& doublearray)`.

An alternative way using C Pointers (thanks Vladimir) could look like:

```
extern "C" void C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN(double ** doublearray)
{
    double *arr = new double [10];
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) 
        arr[i]= i;
    *doublearray = arr;
}
```

Using the fix that Vladimir suggested, the Fortran code reads

```
program test
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN(cdoublearray) BIND(C, NAME='C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
      IMPLICIT NONE
      TYPE(C_PTR)  :: cdoublearray
    END SUBROUTINE 
  END INTERFACE

  TYPE(C_PTR) :: cdoublearray
  REAL(C_DOUBLE), POINTER :: fdoublearray(:)

  CALL C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN( cdoublearray )
  CALL C_F_POINTER( cdoublearray, fdoublearray,[10])

  WRITE (*, *) 'fdoublearray',fdoublearray
END program
```

Then, the output is

```
./a.out 
 fdoublearray   0.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000        5.0000000000000000        6.0000000000000000        7.0000000000000000        8.0000000000000000        9.0000000000000000
```

Comment: The `&` means the C++ reference, it is not supported in `extern "C"` functions, and is not formally supported by Fortran's `bind(C)`, although it is usually implemented as a pointer. The C pointers `*` should be used.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. I modified as you suggested, but the result is the same.

Comment: Just place a second star there, instead of the ampersand. Now you have a pointer to a C++ reference.

Comment: OH MY GOD! just the `(cdoublearray)` lead to the error! after I changed the line `CALL C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN((cdoublearray))` to `CALL C_ASSIGN_ARRAY_TO_FORTRAN(cdoublearray)`, everything is OK! I mean after used the reference &. How to explain this difference? Thanks

Comment: @Alexander & VladimirF Thank you very much

Comment: @TangLaoya You said in the comment that you have just `(cdoublearray)`, undeleting my answer with the explanation.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt it should work. But don't forget to dereference it! `*doublearay`.